# Error with jni (java6) and X25 native code (C language) when code uses system call "connect()" on Solaris 5.9

Tags: java, java-native-interface, solaris

In past years, we created a program that uses X25 protocol. It was made in C language and works fine for a Sun-Fire machine with Solaris 5.9.
Recently, we are working with java 6 in same machine, and we are trying to adapt that old program in C for working with java via jni. 
So I have done some modifications to the old C program and created a shared library named  `x25lib.so`

But I have found a runtime problem using jni and X25: When the C function is invoked from java via jni, the C code does not work in a same way that when it is invoked from another C program.

Concrete, using jni, the C code in shared library works fine until is invoked the system call `connect()`, then returns -1,

But invoking the same C code of my shared library from another C program returns 0  (ok)

In both cases, the C code in shared library doesn´t receive external parameters so the conditions are the same, I don´t understand if loading my "x25lib.so" shared library from java have a little difference that induce `connect()` in C fails.

using "truss" command from java I have found the error:

```
/2: connect(5, 0xFD878B75, 112, 1)          Err#22 EINVAL
```

the same, but invoking the shared lib from another C program:

```
connect(4, 0xFFBFE794, 114, 1)          = 0
```

So it works ok only with pure C,

**Is there another consideration for using jni and X25 for solaris 5.9?**

IMPORTANT: C Code in shared library is identical in both cases.

COMPILATION TIME:

a. Creating `x25lib.so`

```
    cc  -w -fd -G -Kpic subs.o -L/opt/SUNWconn/lib -R/opt/SUNWconn/lib -lsockx25
        -lsocket -lnsl -I"/SDK/jdk/include/" -I"/SDK/jdk/include/solaris/"
        -o x25lib.so -h x25lib.so x25jni.c
```

b. Creating a test C program with that shared library:

```
    cc -w x25lib.so -o x25test x25test.c

where `x25test.c` contains:


    #include <stdio.h>
    main()
    {
        java_x25();
    }
```

c. Using java:

```
public class X25 {

        static {
           System.load("/home/x25lib.so");
        }
    public native void ejecutaComando();
}
```

---

```
public class TestX25 {

    public static void main(String ... args) {
    X25 x25 = new X25();

    x25.ejecutaComando();
    }

}
```

---

Then in C code shared library:

```
/*
 * Class:     X25
 * Method:    ejecutaComando
 * Signature: ()V
 */
JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_X25_ejecutaComando
  (JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{

        java_x25();

}
```

---

So finally both programs (java y C) call exactly the same C code in shared library:

java_x25()
 Without parameters, so execute the same code.

**Why works fine when is called from C, but fails when is called from java?**

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Are you sure your standalone 'C' code is identical to your JNI code?

Comment: Thanks for your answer EJP. Yes, the code is identical, that is my frustation.   I edit my question and add the jni code where you can see it is invoked the same code that in standalone C code.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your comments. I have found a solution while I was trying another approach: I decided not using jni, instead I adapted the old C program for listening for simple tcp connections from java and then could execute x25 code, but surprise, I got the same runtime error like using jni:

```
connect(5, 0xFD8789C5, 112, 1)          Err#22 EINVAL
```

including a size of 112 instead 114, it was the same problem.

So I noticed that the problem was that I had compiled the new C program with **"-lsocket"**  option before **"-lsockx25"**, so that was a clue.  Then I searched in google and I found a similar problem:

[link to java X25 Bug ID:4077576](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug;jsessionid=33cfb04f1c1bf91436be2f2a2f8?bug_id=4077576)

At the end of that article, it is mentioned the option **LD_PRELOAD** to force sockx25 library be loaded first.   Finally the solution was at runtime:

`bash$ export LD_PRELOAD=/opt/SUNWconn/lib/libsockx25.so`

`bash$ java TestX25`

and then all is working fine using jni.

Reference for LD_PRELOAD: [link to java tuning](http://java.sun.com/performance/reference/whitepapers/tuning.html)

Answer (score 0):

Some observations (please post your code if you would like us to go deeper on this -- in particular the part that sets up the parameters to `connect()`):

*Assuming* X.25 over TCP(?):

1. From the man page `EINVAL` is returned from `connect(3socket)` "namelen is not the size of a valid address for the specified address family" where `namelen` is the `sockaddr` structure defined in `<sys/socket_impl.h>`. `namelen` is typically 16 (a 2-byte address family (I'd expect `SOCK_STREAM`) followed by 14 octets of address data). Your program returns `namelen` 112 or 114.
2. The address of `name` in your failing `truss(1)` output above 0xFD878B75 is odd (odd in the sense "not even"). Given Solaris' typical alignment requirements this seems strange. (SPARC or x86? What compiler and flags?). Perhaps a pointer or sizeof problem?
3. From your `truss(1)` output can see that threads are being used in the java invocation. Are your libraries thread-safe?